# программа по языку с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, числа

Даны 2 целых числа а и в. ПРОВЕРИТЬ  ИСТИННОСТЬ ВЫСКАЗЫВАНИЯ : "РОВНО ОДНО ЧИСЛО ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ НЕЧЕТНЫМ"

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

 int a, b;
 cin >> a >> b;

 cout << (a % 2 ^ b % 2 ? "Условие истино" : "Условие ложно") << endl;

 return 0;
}

Answer (score 3):

И в чем проблема?

```
if ((a+b)%2) { ... ровно одно нечетное ... }
```